# How to add plain HTML & CSS in place of the WordPress featured image

Tags: wordpress

I have this HTML & CSS code which I'm using to generate updated images dynamically. I am using Z-index to manipulate the images. One of the images is constant and is the background image. The other two images change and are on top of the background image. I have used style to keep them well aligned on the background image. I will choose what image to show depending on the post content so that is not a problem. I want to use this simple html and some style which I'll apply.

I found a suggestion here https://www.isitwp.com/add-html-to-feature-image-metabox/ but this seems like it's just adding more description to the image. What I have in my html are basically images stacked together into one with the top two images changeable. Is this possible even if it means using the default background image as the basis so that we still have the two images showing plus the background? Please help if you understand what I'm trying to do here. Thanks

`<div id="backg">
            <div id="picback"><img src="\images\picback.png" alt="description"></div>
            <div id="pica">Name A</div>
            <div id="picb">Name B</div>
            <div id="picaback"><img src="\images\imga.png" alt="description"></div>
            <div id="picbback"><img src="\images\imgb.png" alt="description"></div>
            <div id="picalogo"><img src="\images\abc.png" alt="description"></div>
            <div id="picblogo"><img src="\images\cba.png" alt="description"></div>
</div>`

Comment: So, if you have a post with a featured image (and some content) - assuming your background image is static and always the same, where is the second image supposed to come from?

Comment: I think you will need extra images uploaded to post to complete this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32994/add-a-meta-box-for-uploading-a-second-featured-image

Comment: No. The post does not have a featured image. I want to set one using the process described above. Slightly similar to svg because of the nature of image (document not really an image). Mine is not an Svg as you may have already noticed.

Comment: I need to output the above code when I call the `the_post_thumbnail(); `function. Is this a possible way? So that instead of the output being normal html tags `<img src="" alt="">` etc I can have it call a custom field which I will create and add the html inside.